# Blank dates return as Jan 1st when converting to date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I'm reading a dataframe from excel and when I try to convert one column to date, I'm getting instead of the blank value this date 0001-01-01.

```
data['Actual Completion Date'] = [datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in data['Actual Completion Date']]
```

How can I just have a blank value instead of this weird date?

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
df.loc[dateColumn == '0001-01-01', 'dateColumn'] = None
```

Comment: is the first date column a string?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! I put it as a string but it should be able to be done with datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statement to check if its blank:
(I'm not sure what kind of value you have for "blank" so here's some options)

```
# if by blank you mean None
data['Actual Completion Date'] = [datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in data['Actual Completion Date'] if d is not None]
# if by blank you mean empty string
data['Actual Completion Date'] = [datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in data['Actual Completion Date'] if d != ""]
# if by blank you don't know if you mean None or empty string
data['Actual Completion Date'] = [datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in data['Actual Completion Date'] if d]
```

Comment: The blank I have is translated through Panads as NaT.

Answer (score 0):

A simple replacement transformation after you've constructed the dataframe might work.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Example:
    dataframe.replace(thing_to_replace, thing_you_want)

```
dates = ['0001-01-01','1990-01-01','2001-01-01','0001-01-01']
data  = {'Actual Completion Date':dates}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Actual Completion Date'].replace('0001-01-01', '')

  Actual Completion Date
0                       
1             1990-01-01
2             2001-01-01
3
```